# Appsync VTL to js resolver with mysql serverless

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, resolver

This is how js resolver file looks like from aws docs:

```
import {util} from '@aws-appsync/utils';

export function request(ctx) {
    console.log("CTX", ctx);
    return {};
}

export function response(ctx) {
    console.log("result....");
    console.log(ctx.prev.result);
    return ctx.prev.result;
}
```

my question is:

1. how can I put this in my amplify app? which folder? which file should I modify to let it pickup?
2. I am using mysql serverless v1 with data api turned on, how can I run sql statements here? where do they go? I know how it works in vtl, but here I cannot find any examples.